# How to get the age of a tweet?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm importing some tweets using the Search API and get the returning JSON:

```
"results": [
    {
        "created_at": "Thu, 12 Apr 2012 04:58:01 +0000",
        "from_user": "AdamHills",
        "from_user_id": 23045431,
        "from_user_id_str": "23045431",
        "from_user_name": "Adam Hills",
        "geo": null,
        "id": 190302731255287800,
        "id_str": "190302731255287808",
        "iso_language_code": "sv",
        "metadata": {
            "result_type": "recent"
        },
        "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1350305654/goteborgs-rape_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1350305654/goteborgs-rape_normal.jpg",
        "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/#!/download/iphone&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Twitter for iPhone&lt;/a&gt;",
        "text": "@Adde77 Den ska finnas tillgänglig i slutet av april.",
        "to_user": "Adde77",
        "to_user_id": 99782511,
        "to_user_id_str": "99782511",
        "to_user_name": "Adde P",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 190222715716763650,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "190222715716763648"
    }
```

How can I get the age of that particular tweet, so I can print out something like `4m ago` on my page? That, `created_at` string looks a mess! Is there an easy way?

Comment: Check this code to see how its done https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-prettydate/blob/master/jquery.prettydate.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format is standard.

Just construct a Date object from it, then manipulate it as you wish.

```
var tweet_date = new Date("Thu, 12 Apr 2012 04:58:01 +0000");
```